# How to set a switch to a random color

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a [basic switch](https://jsfiddle.net/COdeRonI2/udo36wa8/1/)

```
<body>
<label class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="slider"></span>
</label>
</body>

    .toggle {
  --width: 80px;
  --height: calc(var(--width) / 3);

  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: var(--height);
  cursor: pointer;
 }

.toggle input {
  display: none;
 }

.toggle .slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: var(--height);
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }

.toggle .slider::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--height));
  height: calc(var(--height));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }

.toggle input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
 }

.toggle input:checked+.slider::before {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - var(--height)));
 }
```

that I want to make change colors when it's pressed. But I want the color to be random, preferably every time.

The solution is probably either something to do with the .enabled/disabled states and somehow changing the specific background-color or a completely different language/library. Either way, or if I just went at it wrong, I can't figure it out.

Comment: To pick up random colors you'll need some Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function randomize() {
  document.getElementById('btn').style.backgroundColor = randomColors();
}


// random colors - taken from here:
// http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

function randomColors() {
  return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
```

```css
 .toggle {
  --width: 80px;
  --height: calc(var(--width) / 3);

  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: var(--height);
  cursor: pointer;
 }

.toggle input {
  display: none;
 }

.toggle .slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: var(--height);
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }

.toggle .slider::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--height));
  height: calc(var(--height));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }

.toggle input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
 }

.toggle input:checked+.slider::before {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - var(--height)));
 }
```

```html
<body>
<label class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" >
<span class="slider" id="btn" onclick="randomize()"></span>
</label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's (*probably*) not doable in pure HTML+CSS. With JS, it's quite straightforward: listen on element being clicked, every time generate a random color and change the element's style. A quick and dirty prototype:

```
const checkedSlider = document.querySelector(".toggle .slider");

const randomInt = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

checkbox.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    const r = randomInt(256);
    const g = randomInt(256);
    const b = randomInt(256);
    checkedSlider.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r},${g}, ${b})`
  } else {
    checkedSlider.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ryxvpdog/